# How to submit the modal to the controller and refresh the ajax after the modal dialog for edit closes

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

**Here is my scenario:**

I am using uikit to display a dialog in the home page as follows:

```
<div id="modalEdit" class="uk-modal">
    <div class="uk-modal-dialog uk-modal-dialog-slide">
        <a href="" class="uk-modal-close uk-close"></a>
    </div>
</div>
```

When user click on this, it displays the employee list.

```
<div class="category">
            <span><a class="mainLink" data-url="@Url.Action("Index","Employee",  new {Area="Application"})" href="javascript:void(0);">Employee</a> </span>

            <div class="subCategory">

                <a href="#modalEdit" data-uk-modal onclick="editEmployee()"></a>
            </div>
            <a class="expand"><img src="~/Images/down-arrow.png" /></a>
</div>

<script>
$('.mainLink').click(function() {
        var a = $(this);

        var link = a.attr('data-url');

        if (link.length > 0)
            {

        $.ajax({
            url: link,

            success: function(data) {
                $('#output').html(data);
            },

            error: function(data) {
                $('#output').html("<h2> No results found</h2>");
            }
        });
        }
    });
</script>
```

This is my cshtml file for Editing the modal.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    <fieldset>
        <legend>EmployeeViewModel</legend>

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.EmployeeId, new {id="employeeId"})

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName, new {id="employeeFirstName"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MiddleName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MiddleName, new {id="employeeMiddleName"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MiddleName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastName, new {id="employeeLastName"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" data-url="@Url.Action("Edit", "Employee", new { Area = "Application" })" value="Save"/>
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

<script>
    $('form').submit(function() {
        var $form = $(this);
        //alert($('#employeeId').val());
        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            url: $form.attr('data-url'),
            data: {
                EmployeeId: $('#employeeId').val(),
                FirstName: $('#employeeFirstName').val(),
                MiddleName: $('#employeeMiddleName').val(),
                LastName: $('#employeeLastName').val()
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $('#modalEdit').hide('slow');
                loadEmployee();
                //alert(data);
            },
            error: function(data) {
                alert("failed " + data);
            }
        });

        return false;
    });

    function loadEmployee() {
        //alert("hi");
        $.ajax({
            url: 'Application/Employee/Index',

            success: function (data) {
                //alert(data);
                $('#output').html(data);
            }
        });

    }
</script>
```

When the user edits in the modal dialog, the data should be sent to the controller:

```
//
// GET: /Application/Employee/Edit/5

public ActionResult Edit(int id = 0)
{
    EmployeeVm employeeviewmodel =new EmployeeVm(id);
    if (employeeviewmodel.EmployeeId<1)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }
    return View(employeeviewmodel);
}

//
// POST: /Application/Employee/Edit/5

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Edit(EmployeeVm employeeviewmodel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        EmployeeEditVm employee=new EmployeeEditVm(employeeviewmodel);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    return View(employeeviewmodel);
}
```

Then, the modal dialog should close and update the home page employee data.

My viewmodal:

```
public class EmployeeVm : ConventionInjection
    {
        private StringBuilder stringBuilder;

        public EmployeeVm(Employee employee)
        {
            this.InjectFrom<Employee>(employee);
        }

        public EmployeeVm(int id)
            : this(new Context().Employees.Find(id))
        {

        }

        public EmployeeVm()
        {

        }

        public int EmployeeId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Pleae enter First Name"), StringLength(50)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Middle Name"), StringLength(50)]
        public string MiddleName { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Last Name"), StringLength(50)]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please enter Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        public string FullName()
        {
            stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            stringBuilder.Append("<b>");
            stringBuilder.Append(LastName.ToUpper());
            stringBuilder.Append("</b>");
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(MiddleName))
            {
                stringBuilder.Append(", ");
                stringBuilder.Append(MiddleName);
            }
            stringBuilder.Append(", ");
            stringBuilder.Append(FirstName);
            return stringBuilder.ToString();
        } 

        protected override bool Match(ConventionInfo c)
        {

            bool isMatch=((c.SourceProp.Name == "EmployeeId" && c.TargetProp.Name == "PersonId") ||
                    (c.SourceProp.Name == c.TargetProp.Name && c.SourceProp.Type==c.TargetProp.Type));
            return isMatch;
        }
    }
```

Although, I have shown whole cshtml page for edit, homw page and view modal, its only the jquery/ ajax that is not working as desired. The all other code are tested and works fine.

**This is my question:**
So, how can I pass data to the controller and refresh the employee list as soon as modal dialog closes?

Thanx in advance to all viewers and also for helping me.

Comment: you show the ajax call for populating the partial view but you don't show the ajax call for sending the changed data back to the controller.  can you include that?  You said it isn't working.  what isn't working about it?

Comment: I am using the script below "This is my cshtml file for Editing the modal." line to post back the changed data to the controller.

Comment: I see it now.  what you have posted will send data to the 4 variables that you have defined.  if you want them to populate in a model you need to define an object in the jquery with the same design and populate it.  That or just accept the 4 variables on the controller and save them that way,  may be easier

Comment: I used JSON.stringify to convert the data into object even though its not posting back to the controller. It should post data to Edit action of the Employee Controller as shown in data-url.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

stringify just converts it to json,  it doesn't convert it to a model.  Since your ajax call has

```
EmployeeId: $('#employeeId').val(),
FirstName: $('#employeeFirstName').val(),
MiddleName: $('#employeeMiddleName').val(),
LastName: $('#employeeLastName').val()
```

you need to change your controller to

```
public ActionResult Edit(int EmployeeId, string FirstName, string MiddleName, string LastName){
    //do something with the data
}
```

if you want to pass an object back to the controller you need to do something like

```
var employeeviewmodel = {};
employeeviewmodel.EmployeeId = $('#employeeId').val();
employeeviewmodel.FirstName = $('#employeeFirstName').val();
employeeviewmodel.MiddleName = $('#employeeMiddleName').val();
employeeviewmodel.LastName = $('#employeeLastName').val();
```

then stringify employeeviewmodel in your ajax call.  The name that you define on the view side has to match exactly what you are looking for on the controller side

Comment: I choosed your second option and did as you said ... created object, then used JSON.stringify(employeeviewmodal) in the ajax call. Even though I can't see the break point in the controller being hit. If I check the modal, I have only 3 properties EmployeeId, FirstName, MiddleName and LastName. I couldn't still figure out. sorry.

Comment: if you use a script debugger like firebug or chrome dev tools can you look at the view model object and make sure that it is populating correctly?  You said you were only seeing 3 fields but listed 4

Comment: The problem was caused due to the antifrogerytoken. So, I used "var data = $(this).closest('form').serialize();" to solve the issue. No issue with antiforgerytoken as the whole form was serialized.

Comment: glad you were able to get it fixed

Comment: Thanx alot for the solution. I appreciate your passion, helpful nature and guidance. The thing I liked most was the way you guided me towards the solution. You are genius.. Thanx one more time.

Answer (score 1):

**My final code after the problem was solved (Only need to modify this bit of code):**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
     @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

   <fieldset>
        <legend>EmployeeViewModel</legend>

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.EmployeeId)

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.FirstName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MiddleName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.MiddleName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MiddleName)
        </div>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LastName)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName)
        </div>

        <p>
            <input type="submit" id="Save"  value="Save"/>
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

<script>

    $('#Save').click(function(event) {

        event.preventDefault();
        var data = $(this).closest('form').serialize();

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Application/Employee/Edit',
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            success: function(data) {

                $('#modalEdit').hide('slow');
                loadEmployee();
                alert(data.msg);
            },
            error: function() {

            }
        });
    });

    function success_callback() {
        $('#modalEdit').hide('slow');
        loadEmployee();
        return false;
    }


    function loadEmployee() {
        //alert("hi");
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Application/Employee/Index',

            success: function (data) {
                //alert(data);
                $('#output').html(data);
            }
        });

    }
</script>
```